# Alamofire 3.0 ReactiveCocoa Conversion

Tags: swift, alamofire, reactive-cocoa

I'm having a lot trouble converting my old `Alamofire 2.0` to `3.0` in `ReactiveCocoa`. I keep getting an unknown identifier error on my `sendNext` and `sendCompleted` calls.

```
public final class Network: Networking {
private let queue = dispatch_queue_create( "Beet.BeetModel.Network.Queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)

public init() { }

public func requestJSON(url: String, parameters: [String : AnyObject]?)
    -> SignalProducer<AnyObject, NetworkError>
{
    return SignalProducer { observer, disposable in
        let serializer = Alamofire.Request.JSONResponseSerializer()
        Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: parameters)
            .response(queue: self.queue, responseSerializer: serializer) {
                _, _, result in
                switch result {
                case .Success(let value):
                    sendNext(observer, value)
                    sendCompleted(observer)
                case .Failure(_, let error):
                    sendError(observer, NetworkError(error: error))
                }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This syntax [changed in `4.0 alpha 2`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/pull/2442). `Observer` is now its own type so the old functions `sendNext`, `sendError`, etc are no longer free functions:

```
switch result {
case .Success(let value):
    observer.sendNext(value)
    observer.sendCompleted()
case .Failure(_, let error):
    observer.sendError(NetworkError(error: error))
}
```

One thing I would add to your solution is to provide a disposable so that requests can be cancelled if needed, to save resources:

```
return SignalProducer { observer, disposable in
    let serializer = Alamofire.Request.JSONResponseSerializer() 
    let request = Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: parameters)

    request.response(queue: self.queue, responseSerializer: serializer) { _, _, result in
        switch result {
        case .Success(let value):
            observer.sendNext(value)
            observer.sendCompleted()
        case .Failure(_, let error):
            observer.sendError(NetworkError(error: error))
        }
    }

    disposable.addDisposable(request.cancel)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `observer.sendNext(value)` and ditto for `sendCompleted` and `sendError`